# Is there a dplyr function to determine the most commonly encountered categorical value within a group?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-summaries

I am looking to summarize a customer transactional dataframe to a single row per customer using dplyr.  For continuous variables this is simple - use sum / mean etc.  For categorical variables I would like to choose the "Mode" - i.e. the most commonly encountered value within the group and do this across multiple columns e.g.:

For example to take the table Cus1

```
Cus <- data.frame(Customer = c("C-01", "C-01", "C-02", "C-02", "C-02", "C-02", "C-03", "C-03"),
             Product = c("COKE", "COKE", "FRIES", "SHAKE", "BURGER", "BURGER", "CHICKEN", "FISH"),
              Store = c("NYC", "NYC", "Chicago", "Chicago", "Detroit", "Detroit", "LA", "San Fran")
              )
```

And generate the table Cus_Summary:

```
Cus_Summary <- data.frame(Customer = c("C-01", "C-02", "C-03"),
              Product = c("COKE", "BURGER", "CHICKEN"),
              Store = c("NYC", "Chicago", "LA")
              )
```

Are there any packages that can provide this function?  Or has anyone a function that can be applied across multiple columns within a dplyr step?

I am not worried about smart ways to handle ties - any output for a tie will suffice (although any suggestions as to how to best handle ties would be interesting and appreciated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
Cus %>%
    group_by(Customer) %>%
    summarise(
        Product = first(names(sort(table(Product), decreasing = TRUE))),
        Store = first(names(sort(table(Store), decreasing = TRUE))))
## A tibble: 3 x 3
#  Customer Product Store
#  <fct>    <chr>   <chr>
#1 C-01     COKE    NYC
#2 C-02     BURGER  Chicago
#3 C-03     CHICKEN LA
```

Note that in the case of ties this selects the first entry in alphabetical order.

---

### Update

To *randomly* select an entry from tied top frequency entries we could define a custom function

```
top_random <- function(x) {
    tbl <- sort(table(x), decreasing = T)
    top <- tbl[tbl == max(tbl)]
    return(sample(names(top), 1))
}
```

Then the following randomly selects one of the tied top entries:

```
Cus %>%
    group_by(Customer) %>%
    summarise(
        Product = top_random(Product),
        Store = top_random(Store))
```

Comment: Your's solution do not consider the case where more than one value is most frequent.

Comment: @PawełChabros Yes it does; in the case of ties it choses the first entry in alphabetical order. Additionally, see RonakShah's and OPs comment regarding ties. Your downvotes are quite unwarranted.

Comment: Ok. My bad. I will reverse my downvote if you will do some edit :)

Comment: Should be possible here as well.

Comment: @PawełChabros your turn;-)

Comment: I like this - it's succinct and easily readable.  A couple of questions:

1 - are there any memory issues if this is to be applied to a large data frame?  Does the generation of the table within the group when applied thousands of times pose any problems?

2 - now I think about the ties issue some more, is it possible to select a result at random rather than the first alphabetically to avoid creating a bias in the resultant output? :-)

Comment: @BrisbanePom Concerning 1: I find this difficult to answer; in the end a benchmark analysis will tell. However, `tidyverse` solutions are not usually geared towards speed. If speed/memory issues are your concern, a `data.table` solution might be better, but again this will depend on your specific data. Concerning 2: Interesting suggestion. I've made an edit to show how to randomly select entries from ties.

Comment: As is typical when applying code to the real world application, a problem has arisen - I am getting errors (probably due to missing values causing the function to crash).  Any chance you could update that top_random function with a Try / Catch construct Maurits, as my kack-handed attempt failed!

Comment: @BrisbanePom More than happy to take a look at it. Would you be able to post some minimal sample data that reproduces the errors you're getting?

Comment: Just o improve a little bit, add `if(all(is.na(x))){ return("") }` in case your column only has NA (all are missing values).

Answer (score 0):

If you have many columns and want to find out maximum occurrence in all the columns you could use `gather` to convert the data in long format, `count` the occurrence for each column, `group_by` `Customer` and column and keep only the rows with maximum count and then `spread` it back to wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

Cus %>%
  gather(key, value, -Customer) %>%
  count(Customer, key, value) %>%
  group_by(Customer, key) %>%
  slice(which.max(n)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  select(-n)

# Customer Product Store  
#  <fct>    <chr>   <chr>  
#1 C-01     COKE    NYC    
#2 C-02     BURGER  Chicago
#3 C-03     CHICKEN LA
```

---

**EDIT**

In case of ties if we want to randomly select ties we can `filter` all the `max` values and then use `sample_n` function to select random rows.

```
Cus %>%
  gather(key, value, -Customer) %>%
  count(Customer, key, value) %>%
  group_by(Customer, key) %>%
  filter(n == max(n)) %>%
  sample_n(1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  spread(key, value) %>%
  select(-n)


# Customer Product Store   
#  <fct>    <chr>   <chr>   
#1 C-01     COKE    NYC     
#2 C-02     BURGER  Chicago 
#3 C-03     FISH    San Fran
```

Comment: Your's solution do not consider the case where more than one value is most frequent.

Comment: @PawełChabros OP mentioned `I am not worried about smart ways to handle ties - any output for a tie will suffice`. IMO, taking taking first max value would be included in "any output for tie".

Comment: @PawełChabros you should be able to do that now.

Comment: Yes, this works well for my original question where ties are not an issue.  Now I've thought about it, would there be a way to apply the slice for max(n) in such a way that the resultant slice value is selected at random?  Would be interested to compare an approach under this method with the two approaches given above.

Comment: @BrisbanePom We can `filter` all the `max` values and then use `sample_n` to select random rows. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my solution, if there are more than one most frequent value, all are presented:

```
library(tidyverse)

Cus %>%
  gather('type', 'value', -Customer) %>%
  group_by(Customer, type, value) %>%
  count() %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  filter(n == max(n)) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(
    Product = map_chr(data, ~str_c(filter(.x, type == 'Product') %>% pull(value), collapse = ', ')),
    Store = map_chr(data, ~str_c(filter(.x, type == 'Store') %>% pull(value), collapse = ', '))
  ) %>%
  select(-data)
```

Result is:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Customer Product       Store           
  <fct>    <chr>         <chr>           
1 C-01     COKE          NYC             
2 C-02     BURGER        Chicago, Detroit
3 C-03     CHICKEN, FISH LA, San Fran
```

Comment: If we could choose one of the two variants at random, rather than join the strings by a comma, this solution may be the best way to pick a random value from the tie to ensure bias does not get introduced as it would by the alphabetical-first method (see comment in answer given above)

Answer (score 0):

Using [SO's favourite Mode function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547402/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-finding-the-mode) (though you could use any):

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}
```

**In base R**

```
aggregate(. ~ Customer, lapply(Cus,as.character),  Mode)
#   Customer Product   Store
# 1     C-01    COKE     NYC
# 2     C-02  BURGER Chicago
# 3     C-03 CHICKEN      LA
```

**using *`dplyr`***

```
library(dplyr)
Cus %>%
  group_by(Customer) %>%
  summarise_all(Mode)

# # A tibble: 3 x 3
# Customer Product   Store
# <fctr>  <fctr>  <fctr>
# 1     C-01    COKE     NYC
# 2     C-02  BURGER Chicago
# 3     C-03 CHICKEN      LA
```